# Custom sort to map trough the constructor

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-function

I don't know how to pass a custom sort behavior to a `std::map` in the following way:

```
Constructor(const std::function<bool(const Obj&, const Obj&)>& ac_xNewComparator)
: mNewMap(xNewComparator(/*...???....*/)) {}
```

How could I pass the comparator to the map?

Comment: Try mNewMap(type1,type2, ax_xNewComparator) - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/

Comment: @hired777: You're mixing up the template arguments (the types) and the constructor argument (the comparator). It's just `mNewMap(ac_xNewComparator)`, as long as the map type is instantiated with a suitable comparator type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Test
{
public:

    Test(const std::function<bool (int x, const std::string& str)>& comparator)
        : m_map(comparator)
    {
    }

    std::map<int, std::string, std::function<bool (int x, const std::string& str)> > m_map;

};
```